# query XML file in a sql script

Tags: hana

In HANA, I need information on calculation view like cross client or not, commentary on node, cardinality...

Those information are in XML file of the calculation view. Is it possible to extract it with a procedure?

During my research I found this : https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/3600091

I hoped that now it would be possible.

If you have any idea, please share with me,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I'm replying to the question on getting the metadata or attributes from a view. You can probably find these in tables like _sys_bi.bimc_* (e.g. BIMC_PROPERTIES in the _SYS_BI schema), SYS.VIEWS, SYS.VIEW_COLUMNS, SYS.cs_view_parameters (has the client as a parameter) or sys.view_columns.

I think it's easier to extract this information from the automatic documentation file in PDF format from HANA Studio, though, but it depends on what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have already looked at these tables and unfortunately there are not the information I'm looking for. I will think at your idea, thanks for your answer Lucia